# Component wont render

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs, components

I am passing an array of objects to `TileFeed` and am taking out thumbnail URLS to be used for each tile on the page. The URLS are being extracted, but the actual tile isn't rendering for some reason. When I console out the `thumb.thumbnail` I get the correct output.[image]

```
class TileFeed extends Component {
  render() {
    const { thumbnail } = this.props;
    return thumbnail.map(thumb => {
      console.log(thumb.thumbnail);
      <div key={thumb._id} className="row__inner">
        <div className="tile">
          <div className="tile__media">
            <img
              className="tile__img"
              id="thumbnail"
              src={thumb.thumbnail}
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>;
    });
  }
}
```

**Class that calls TileFeed**

```
render() {
    const { videos, loading, key } = this.props.videos;
    let videoContent;
    if (videos === null || loading) {
      videoContent = <Spinner />;
    } else {
      videoContent = <TileFeed thumbnail={videos} />;
    }
    console.log({ videoContent });

    return (
      <div className="explore">
        <div className="row">{videoContent} </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the JSX from the function given to `map`. Add a return statement or remove the function body `{}` to make the return implicit.

```
class TileFeed extends Component {
  render() {
    const { thumbnail } = this.props;
    return thumbnail.map(thumb => {
      return (
        <div key={thumb._id} className="row__inner">
          <div className="tile">
            <div className="tile__media">
              <img
                className="tile__img"
                id="thumbnail"
                src={thumb.thumbnail}
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}
```